# Frama-C: Getting function outputs when using pointers

Tags: c, frama-c

I need to get a list of all the outputs of a function. When I use the `From`-plugin on the following code

```
void add(int *sum, int a, int b)
{
    *sum = a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int result;
    add(&result, 1, 2);
}
```

it tells me that `result` is the output of the `add` function. This is of course correct, but I would like the plugin to mention `sum` somewhere. I know `sum` is a pointer and is not modified in the function, so it is not an output, but `*sum` *is* modified and I would like to know that. Is there an easy (or any) way to achieve this?

Comment: Why would it mention `sum`, which is *local* to the function?

Comment: @DaviD. What is  From-plugin ?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am implementing a code-transformation that needs to do stuff with all function outputs before the function returns. I know `sum` is local and is not modified, but it points to a value outside the function and that value is modified and thus an output of the function. So it would be really nice if `*sum` would be reported as an output.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It tells you on which other variables a specific variable depends on. When using the command-line you can use `-deps` to display these dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `add` as your main entry point, you might be able to retrieve the information you want:

```
$ frama-c -main add -deps file.c
[...]
[from] ====== DEPENDENCIES COMPUTED ======
   These dependencies hold at termination for the executions that terminate:
[from] Function add:
  S_sum[0] FROM sum; a; b
```

Basically, `S_sum[0]` is `*sum`: `Value` (on which `From` relies) generates an initial state in which pointers are either `NULL` or pointing to a block with a name similar to the one of the pointer and having, by default, two elements. There are command line options to tweak the default behavior (see [Value Analysis manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-value-analysis.pdf) for more information on that), but you might find out that for more complex examples you need to write (or generate) a wrapper function that will set up a more complex initial state before calling the function. In that case, you'll have to keep track of which pointer points to where in order to reconstruct the information.

The bulk of the issue is that in the abstract state of `Value`, `sum` is mapped to a set `L` of possible locations (here reduced to a singleton), but `*sum` is not an object in itself. A write access will simply update all values mapped to elements of `L`. Thus from the point of view of `From` everything looks like a modification of `result` (or `S_sum[0]` if you change the entry point).

Comment: By "wrapper function", do you mean I should write a wrapper around `add` where I use known names for the arguments, like `add(&arg1, arg2, arg3)`, so that I can translate `arg1 FROM sum; a; b` to `*sum FROM sum; a; b`? And: Do the same restrictions apply when using the OCaml bindings? Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DaviD. yes, a wrapper function in this context is a function that set up an appropriate initial state and calls the real entry point of the analysis. I'm unsure what you mean by "using OCaml bindings" though. Do you want to use `Db.Value` and `Db.From` functions instead of grepping the output? This is indeed a good idea, but yes, the same restrictions apply: you won't see `*sum` there.